# How to suppress Google Analytics pings on iOS Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, ios7, google-analytics, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I instantiate a Google Analytics tracker object on my AppDelegate.m > didFinishLaunchingWithOptions event and only tick the tracker on another ViewController's > viewDidAppear event.

But I do instantiate that same ViewController from AppDelegate's > didReceiveRemoteNotification method and call a user-defined method on that ViewController to do something.

My thought was that this shouldn't send a ping to Google Analytics since the ping was only done on the viewDidAppear event of that ViewController. But I've been noticing that every time my app receives a remote notification it's sending a ping to Google Analytics and is messing up in terms of real-time tracking.

I've simulated remote notifications and the viewDidAppear even was not fired during didReceiveRemoteNotification.

Any thoughts on how to do this right? Anyone faced similar issue before?

Comment: Just checking but I assume you are not using the GAITrackedViewController right?

Comment: No, I was not. I manually invoke the [send] message for events and screens. With this at least I thought I have some control.